# How to update colors for object explorer menu in SSMS

Tags: ssms

I am using dark mode on SQL Server and I have tried to update the font and colors for the object explorer menu, but I seem to be unable to find the appropriate settings to update the menu colors from Options > Fonts and Colors.

Here is what my menu looks like when a right-click an object from the Object Explorer

[image: Menu options are too dark to see]

Is there a way to update the text on the right-hand side so it's easier to read?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution for chaning the sub-menu color unless you can inject the dll / exe file of SSMS.

A workaround is here:

https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/making-ssms-pretty-my-dark-theme